# Case Statement results in the Where Clause

Tags: sql-server, case

I have a case statement result that I need to use. I want to place it in the Where clause, but becase of the complexity of the CASE Statement, I am having some difficulties.

Here is my CASE Statement...the results are either "Achieved" or "Not Achieved". I need the "Not Achieved" in the final results.

```
  CASE WHEN (ESF.ID IN   
  ('727','732','737','813','738','739','740','741','742','743') 
   AND b.ANSWER ='Checked') THEN 'Not Achieved'
     WHEN (ESF.ID IN 
      ('727','732','737','813','738','739','740','741','742','743')        
        AND Z.ANSWER ='Unchecked') THEN 'Achieved'
         ELSE ''
     End AS Results_c
```

Comment: My Where Clause should be: 
Where Results_c ='Not Achieved'

Comment: can this be done in a view? I am working in a view that cannot be altered.

Comment: Is this case statement in the view already ?  Is `Results_c` already an output column of the view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CASE` statement processes in such way, that one rule is evaluated at a time starting from thefirst one. As soon as the rules is satisfied (returns `TRUE`) this rule is actioned and check of rules in this `CASE` statemnt ends.

So rewrite your CASE as:

CASE WHEN ESF.Form_Dim_ID NOT IN
      ('727','732','737','813','738','739','740','741','742','743') THEN ''
   WHEN b.ANSWER ='Checked') THEN 'Not Achieved'
   WHEN Z.ANSWER ='Unchecked') THEN 'Achieved'
   ELSE ''
     End AS Results_c

If you need to have only `Not Achieved` then

```
WHERE
[...]
AND (ESF.Form_Dim_ID NOT IN   
         ('727','732','737','813','738','739','740','741','742','743') 
    AND b.ANSWER ='Checked')
    )
```

However it might be very difficult to get expected results, because every next check in this `CASE` statement uses different column and does not cater for other combinations of previous check. E.g.:

```
WHEN ESF.ID IN   ('727','732','737','813','738','739','740','741','742','743')
```

What if `ESF.ID` not in this list? (also why integers referred as strings?)

```
`b.ANSWER ='Checked`  and `Z.ANSWER ='Unchecked'`
```

What if the values are other way round or completely different? And so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter the results of the select statement so that only rows where `Results_c` = the value of the case expression, then just put that to the right of the where clause

```
 Select [stuff]
 From tableName
 Where (ESF.ID IN 
         ('727','732','737','813','738','739','740','741','742','743') 
           And b.ANSWER ='Checked') Or  
       (ESF.ID IN 
         ('727','732','737','813','738','739','740','741','742','743')
           And Z.ANSWER ='Unchecked')
```

In this case, I notice that the two lists of Ids are identical, so you could also write:

```
 Select [stuff]
 From tableName
 Where ESF.ID IN  ('727','732','737','813','738','739','740','741','742','743') 
     And (b.ANSWER = 'Checked' Or Z.ANSWER ='Unchecked')
```

To display only those that have *Not* Achieved,

```
 Select [stuff]
 From tableName
 Where ESF.ID IN  ('727','732','737','813','738','739','740','741','742','743')
           AND b.ANSWER ='Checked'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Have a question...then how would I only display those that have Not Achieved in the results window? This portion is new, since I have never worked with a case statement like this.

Comment: Just modify the filter condiditon predicate in the Where clause to only specify the `Not Achieved` values...... See my edit

Comment: Getting invalid column name on Results_c in the Where Clause.

Comment: Sorry,  yes, I missed that you were trying to also use `Results_c` as an alias of an additional output column. You can do that, but not in the same clause as the filter, which I have edited.